# Is using platinum as a heating element 10x less efficient than using nichrome?

Tags: thermodynamics

I notice that platinum has about ten times less resistivity than nichrome. Does that imply platinum requires 10x as much electricity as nichrome to produce the same amount of heat when used as a resistive heating element?

Comment: Just need more current at a lower voltage to get the same power.

Comment: @JonCuster or thinner wire...which is good news considering the cost of platinum.

Answer (score 3):

No. Assuming the same length and diameter of wire, you'll get the same heat from the platinum element from voltage reduced by a factor of sqrt(10). Of course, by Ohm's law, that means current increased by a factor of sqrt(10).

A resistor converts 100% of the electrical power delivered to it to heat, regardless of its composition.

Comment: A resistor converts 100% of the electrical power delivered to it to heat, but with a lower resistance, more power will be dissipated in the wiring and the power supply itself instead of being carried to the resistor. Higher resistance elements are more efficient, resulting in lower losses elsewhere.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff Yes. Details. But the question wasn't about such details.